# How to compare multiple object values against each other?

Tags: c#, icomparer

Assume i have a object with the following values in it (also please note i do not wish to use a  datetime object for this, just the following values below and i wish to solve this in the comparer itself):

```
int year; 
int month; 
int day;
int sec;
int min;
```

How can i compare all those multiple values in my Comparer against each other so they get listed according date?

Then i wish to make a Comparer.cs class:

```
class MyComparer: IComparer
{
    int sort;

    public MyComparer(int s)
    {
        sort= s;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        Date d1 = (Date)x;
        Date d2 = (Date)y;
        int result= 0;

         // d1.Year.CompareTo(d2.Year);  //get accessors from other class
        // i seem to be limited here by comparing only 1 single value to a other?

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is easy to do it, so please tell us what exactly you don't understand here. And just a minor note: Use IComparer<T>.

Comment: You could also let your `Date` class implement the `IComparable<Date>` interface, so you don't have to cast your objects. Or you could let your `MyComparer` implement the `IComparer<Date>` interface. Difference is the `<>` with the correct types, so you are sure to have the right objects.

Comment: @Al Kepp: Sorry for the double note =) I was already writing this down.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
int result = d1.Year.CompareTo(d2.Year);
if (result != 0) return result;

result = d1.Month.CompareTo(d2.Month);
if (result != 0) return result;

...

return 0;   //All properties were equal
```

Comment: Thanks , and how can i exactly use this in my Other class itself if i wish to declare the CompareTo method there, return this. ..... .CompareTo(....)

Comment: But i mean i dont wish to compare to lets say only year, or minute but the entire load. How can i nicely write that down?  Regards.

Comment: The same way I wrote my answer, but with different CompareTo calls.  Do you understand how my code works?

Comment: Nearly but what happends exactly when its not equal and it returns the result? Bit stuck in my other class how to call upon this. Only been comparing single values without a problem but now i am pretty confused, although i wish to understand this properly. Best regards.

Comment: If `result` is non-zero, it means that you have found a non-matching property.  Thus, the result of the comparison is determined the that property.

Comment: Okay i see, but how would i call upon this exactly in my Class itself then where i declare this CompareTo(Object obj) method? return this.d1.Date.CompareTo(d2.Date) & .... & .... &... does not seem right is it?

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to keep making comparisons until you either have a difference or there is nothing left to compare.

```
int result; 
result = d1.year.CompareTo(d2.year);
if (result == 0)
   result = d1.month.CompareTo(d2.month);
if (result == 0)
   // continue comparisons through day, hour, minute, second as necessary

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start comparing starting with the most significant element first, like this:

```
    public class MyDate : IComparable<MyDate>
    {
        public enum MyMonth { Jan = 1 , Feb , Mar , Apr , May , Jun , Jul , Aug , Sep , Oct , Nov , Dec , }

        public int     Year   ;
        public MyMonth Month  ;
        public int     Day    ;
        public int     Hour   ;
        public int     Minute ;
        public int     Second ;

        private static Comparer _comparerInstance = null ;
        private static Comparer comparerInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if ( _comparerInstance == null )
                {
                    _comparerInstance = new Comparer() ;
                }
                return _comparerInstance ;
            }
        }

        public class Comparer : IComparer<MyDate> 
        {
            #region IComparer<MyDate> Members

            public int Compare(MyDate x, MyDate y)
            {
                if ( x == null || y == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException() ;
                if ( object.ReferenceEquals(x,y) ) return 0 ;

                int rc ;

                if (      x.Year < y.Year ) rc = -1 ;
                else if ( x.Year > y.Year ) rc = +1 ;
                else // x.Year == y.Year
                {
                    if (      x.Month < y.Month ) rc = -1 ;
                    else if ( x.Month > y.Month ) rc = +1 ;
                    else // x.Month == y.Month
                    {
                        if (      x.Day < y.Day ) rc = -1 ;
                        else if ( x.Day > y.Day ) rc = +1 ;
                        else // x.Day == y.Day
                        {
                            if (      x.Hour < y.Hour ) rc = -1 ;
                            else if ( x.Hour > y.Hour ) rc = +1 ;
                            else // x.Hour == y.Hour
                            {
                                if (      x.Minute < y.Minute ) rc = -1 ;
                                else if ( x.Minute > y.Minute ) rc = +1 ;
                                else // x.Minute = y.Minute
                                {
                                    if (      x.Second < y.Second ) rc = -1 ;
                                    else if ( x.Second > y.Second ) rc = -1 ;
                                    else /* x.Second == y.Seconds */ rc = 0 ;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return rc ;
            }
            #endregion
        }

        #region IComparable<MyDate> Members

        public int CompareTo( MyDate other )
        {
            return comparerInstance.Compare( this , other ) ;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

It's just boring plumbing work, no magic to it.