# Can we pass all properties we want to order by all together

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable` object and I can chain `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to it fine but I have like six properties so the chain gets long and ugly!
So I was just wondering if there is a way to list all properties somehow in one go and it would internally do it by the order of appearance of properties that we have passed to it?
I did some Googling around but didn't find much.

Comment: You can implement the interface `IComparable<T>` and then just order it `.OrderBy(r=> r)`.  [How to implement IComperable for multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716792/how-to-compare-multiple-object-values-against-each-other)

Comment: There is no such standard method.

Answer (score -1):

Aside of implementing the custom `IComparable`, you can somehow join fields to use this join as a sort key. E.g you can join two numbers M in 0 to 9999 and N in 1 to 12 as M * 100 + N:

```
OrderBy(o => o.M).ThenBy(o => o.N)

-->

OrderBy(o => o.M * 100 + o.N)
```

This trick can help in some circumstances.